# Implicit Conversion stopped working after updating MySQL Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, casting, connector

I recently upgraded my MySQL Connector C++ to v8.0.16 which lead to problem occurring during the compile of my project.

All the errors are from casting the "mysql::abi2::r0::Value" to different types. 
For example, I have this code inside one of my functions:

```
std::string s; 
sql::Row res; 

... Fetching from database ... 

s = row[0]; // Here is the error
```

The error I'm having is:

> no suitable user-defined conversion from "mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value" to
>   "std::string" exists

But if I use casting it works:

```
s = (std::string)row[0]; // No error here
```

In the previous version of MySQL Connector C++ I didn't have this problem.

I have checked and the mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value class of the MySQL Connector does implement the operator std::string which allows for implicit conversion so is there any reason that my code won't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The errors are from **not** casting. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The change seems to be that the **implicit conversion** that the code relied on is no longer implicit.

Comment: @PeteBecker Correct, but as I see in the code of the MySQL Connector, they have implemented the operator std::string so is there any reason this won't work?

Comment: You declared the variable `res` but never used it. You used the variable `row` but never declared it. Were these supposed to be the same variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently, MySQL has made that the std::string and bool implicit conversion are now explicit conversion, so that was the source of my problem.